# FF/Chrome do not reload mysql data if I go back to the page I came from

Tags: php, browser

I just noticed and odd behavior. I am working in a cms. If I edit the title of a post and click save, it is updated in the mysql database instantly. But if I click on "all posts" to go back to the list of posts the title will not be updated. Only after I refresh the page will the new title be displayed.

The flow is like this.

"All Posts" Page -> click -> "Edit Post" -> click -> "All Posts"

I am guessing that the browser do not reload the data from the mysql database because they think it is still up to date.

This is happening in Firefox 6.0 and Chrome 13.0.782.112, but not in Safari 5.1 on Mac OSX Lion 10.7.1.

Is that the usual behavior? And how do I change it?

I hope my problem is understandable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, this did not help, although it might be just for my problem. What did fix it was to put the following in my .htaccess file.

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
Header unset Last-Modified
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

Does it make sense this way, or should I alter it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell the browser to refresh the page each time you visit it. You can do this by setting the following header:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
```

Comment: But this means, the browser does not cache anything, right? I would like it to work like it used too, some weeks ago, that the browser chaches images and such like, but reloads dynamic content from the database.

Comment: Yes, the browser will not cache your pages after that; but it will still cache images and other static contents.